# Вывести данные на JSP из MySQL с помощью Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, java-ee, jsp

всем привет. хочу вывести данные на JSP из MySQL с помощью Hibernate. Вот так я выводил с использованием JDBC и все работало(это мой тэг, потом я его использую на jsp странице)  :

```
    private int count;
    private String nameTable;

public void setCount(int count){
    this.count = count;
}

public void setNameTable(String nameTable){
    this.nameTable = nameTable;
}


@Override
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
    DB db = DB.getDB("myhealth_db");
    ResultSet rs = db.query("SELECT discription_chapter FROM "+nameTable+"_info WHERE id_article = "+count + " AND id_chapter = 1");
    try {
        if(rs.next()){
            out.write(rs.getString("discription_chapter").substring(0,200));
        } else {
            out.write("No Name");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return SKIP_BODY;

}
```

мне нужно тут все изменить под hibernate. как ?

Comment: Так, как описано в документации: объявляете классы-сущности, настраиваете фабрику сессий, в методе `doStartTag()` получаете сессию из фабрики, делаете с помощью сессии HQL-запрос и обходите циклом полученный список сущностей, выводя нужные поля в `out`.

Comment: это все я знаю,спасибо, но вот тут вопрос : 
ResultSet rs = db.query("SELECT discription_chapter FROM "+nameTable+"_info WHERE id_article = "+count + " AND id_chapter = 1");

в rs я сохраняю необходимые для вывода данные из нужной таблицы,собственно циклом,уже на jsp.
а во что сохранять в hibernate? может какой то пример есть? фабрика настроена, HQL запрос не знаю какой

Comment: сверху изменил код, добавил пару полей, в них я сохраняю названия таблиц с кнопок на самом сайте но HQL запрос не понимаю какой нужен. Поле count для цикла на JSP чтобы выводилось от 1 до 5, поле nameTable для каждой части с сайта,которое соответствует сущности.

Comment: HQL запросы возвращают или один объект сущности, или список (List) объектов сущности, или список массивов объектов (List<Object[]>). В зависимости от вашего запроса.

Comment: все ясно, Сергей спасибо, но вопрос в том, что у меня много таблиц и мне выводить названия подназваний(так сказать) в цикле этим запросом : 
SELECT discription_chapter FROM "+nameTable+"_info WHERE id_article = "+count + " AND id_chapter = 1;  
как же его заменить на HQL ?

Comment: Собирать запрос конкатенацией строк - плохая практика. Это делает вашу программу уязвимой для sql injection. Избавьтесь от этого.

Comment: буду пытаться..когда сделаю напишу ответ..спасибо Сергей вам !

Comment: может все таки есть какой то пример метода doStartTag(); как вообще это должно выглядеть ? уже голову сломал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понятия не имею о структуре ваших данных и требуемом функционале, но этого приблизительного примера должно хватить, как основы для дальнейших самостоятельных поисков решения.

**Article.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Entity
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String description;

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

**SomeTag.java**

```
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class SomeTag extends TagSupport {
    private SessionFactory factory;
    private int count;

    public SomeTag() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistryBuilder srBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
        srBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = srBuilder.buildServiceRegistry();
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    public void setCount(int count){
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Article where id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", count);
        List<Article> articles = query.list();
        for (Article article : articles) {
            out.write(article.getDescription().substring(0, 200));
        }
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Сергей, благодарю вас!